# How to implement negative null floating point regex

Tags: javascript, regex

What could I use as a regex that validates floating point numbers?

The numbers could be negative and cannot start by 0 (unless it is a real 0, or a 0 followed by decimal points such in `0.00123`)

On the other hand, the regex should validate partial/uncompleted numbers. For example:

- ''(empty string) is valid
- `-` is valid (it could still be a valid number with appropiate user input)
- `0` is valid (as `0.1` could be valid)
- `0.0` is valid, for the same previous reason
- `-0.000` is valid
- `-01` is not valid
- `.2` is not valid

I tried with this regexp:

```
 ^(-|-?0\.?[0-9]*|-?[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*|)$
```

It allows me to discard all non-numeric values ​​and still allow fractional values, but how to implement the possibility that the user cannot enter numbers in the format -0232, but can enter -0.232

Comment: Here you can enter examples: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Why is -0232 not allowed but -0.232 allowed? At which point should the distinction be made? What about positive numbers, are there any limitations? Would it be possible for you to change the string to a number and perform your checks there?

Comment: input that allows you to enter fractional numbers, positive and negative can be 0.n but cannot be 0n

Comment: that is, the user cannot enter numbers in the format 0123123 or -03123123, but he is allowed to enter 0.3312312

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I get it right, you want a regex that validates "could-be-a-future-decimal" numbers. So `(empty string)` `-`, `-0`, `0` and `0.`... should be valid.

You may use this regex:

```
^-?(?:(?!0\d)\d+\.?\d*)?$
```

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/ADDiS3/7/).

**Explained:**

```
^             # Start of string
-?            # an optional minus
(?:           # non-capturing group
    (?!0\d)   #    whatever comes next, it cannot be 0 + number
    \d+       #    at least one number
    \.?       #    optional dot
    \d*       #    any quantity of numbers
)?            # previous group is optional
$
```

Also, bear in mind that the previous thing is a regex object. So you should try to use it like this in javascript:

```
/myregex/
```

However, javascript also allows using string-based regexes (which by your comments it seems that is what you want...)

In that case you can use the `new RegExp` syntax. However, bear in mind that since you'll be using a string, you need to scape any characters a string should scape.

For example, you may use:

```js
function return_some_regex_string() {
  // NOTE backslashes had to be scaped since this is a string, 
  //      not a real regex object
  return '^-?(?:(?!0\\d)\\d+\\.?\\d*)?$';
}

console.log("0.123".match(new RegExp(return_some_regex_string())));
console.log("-03233".match(new RegExp(return_some_regex_string())));
console.log("333-3334".match(new RegExp(return_some_regex_string())));
```

But, at the same time, you could already return the regex object, which seems a simpler way to work than using string-based regexes:

```js
function return_some_regex() {
  return /^-?(?:(?!0\d)\d+\.?\d*)?$/;
}

console.log("0.123".match(return_some_regex()));
console.log("-03233".match(return_some_regex()));
console.log("333-3334".match(return_some_regex()));
```

Comment: @frontDev24, Glag it worked! Remember you can "accept" the answer with the green tick

Comment: Can you tell how I can add ability to enter single - in your decision, and ability to leave empty value

Comment: and also ability to return null in case like -03233

Comment: @frontDev24, changed my answer to allow the only '-' and empty string. The case `-03233` was already working... I added some extra checks on the embeded code for you to check

Comment: you are crazy I didnt expect so much help here!thanks

Comment: @frontDev24 I managed to squeeze the regex some more characters, now it is a tad shorter.

Comment: @frontDev24 By the way, you approved "the fourth birth" answer instead of mine. Nothing wrong with it... but at least his answer should be changed in order to reflect the requirements you talked about

Comment: by chance, your solution came up, changed the status, just found a flaw, you can enter 333-3334 numbers in this format, in any case I choose your solution, but if it's not difficult, write down how you can fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220735/discussion-between-frontdev24-and-julio).

Comment: @Julio The solution I provided accounts for all the given scenarios mentioned including the last scenario. Btw, you don't have to use lookarounds and you have to escape the dot  because not it will also match `232Q33`

Comment: oh yeah thanks, this is the finish, I hope it didn't bother you too much)))

Comment: @Thefourthbird, Yes, i missed to scape the dot... :). Sorry, when I checked your answer I don't recall having seen your second regex with the optional group. Anyways, your regex seems to fail with `00.123`. What's the problem with a negative lookahead here?

Comment: @frontDev24 Nowhere does it state that it should not accept `00.123`. There is no problem with it, but you can get the matches without is like the OP's original pattern with the alternation.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, well, it says explcitily nowhere. Requirements were not very clear. But I understand that if `001` is not valid, then `001.0` should also be not valid

Comment: That is is an assumption.

Comment: @Thefourthbird, You also made your own assumption that `001.01` should match. Considering that `001` should not match, I think my assumption of not matching `001.01` was reasonable. But let's just wait what OP says

Comment: @Thefourthbird, also, by reading the comments I think I did **not** actually made an assumption. He said that if the regex does not match, the user 'cannot keep on writing'. So that was the reason to allow `(empty)`, `-` and a single `0` as valids. If the users writes `00` that should validate the string as **invalid**, which will disallow more user input, and this it could not be 'fixed' by adding decimal points (unless deleting extra zeros). So in turn, it would be impossible to write `00.1` even if the regex allows it. So in theory you expect the regex to not match `00.1`

Comment: yes it is just simple input where user enter double value, so I dont need to use -001.2 

but in any case, thank you both for your feedback

Answer (score 2):

You could match an optional hyphen, followed by either a floating point  or match a number starting with 1-9

```
^-?(?:\d+\.\d+|[1-9]\d*|0\.?)$
```

The pattern will match

- `^` Start of string
- `-?` Optional hyphen
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\d+\.\d+` Match 1+ digits, dot and 1+ digits
  - `|` Or
  - `[1-9]\d*` Match a digit 1-9 and 0+ digits 0-9
  - `|` Or
  - `0\.?` Match a zero and optional dot
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wyZWFZ/1)

```js
let pattern = /^-?(?:\d+\.\d+|[1-9]\d*|0\.?)$/;
["-0123",
  "0123123",
  "-03123123",
  "1234",
  "-0.234",
  "0.4",
  "0.3312312",
  "1",
  "-1234",
  "0",
  "0."
].forEach(s => console.log(`${s} match:${pattern.test(s)}`));
```

If you want to match an empty string or just a single hyphen, you can also make the second part optional.

```
^-?(?:\d+\.\d+|[1-9]\d*|0\.?)?$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A2mUhU/1)

Comment: sory but why it dont work like this let res = '3.3'.match('^(?:-?\d+\.\d+|[1-9]\d*)$')

Comment: @frontDev24 Try it like this without the single quotes `let res = '3.3'.match(/^(?:-?\d+\.\d+|[1-9]\d*)$/);

Comment: I need somethins that work with this case
1232
0.1234
-1234
-0.1234

Comment: @frontDev24 I have added a Javascript example for the matches.

Comment: @frontDev24 lo like this then https://regex101.com/r/L5VC2J/1

Comment: Use it like `let pattern = new RegExp("^-?(?:\\d+\\.\\d+|[1-9]\\d*|0\\.?)$");` or shorter like `let pattern = /^-?(?:\d+\.\d+|[1-9]\d*|0\.?)$/;`